# two conflicting jquery scripts

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I've been recently trying to learn how jQuery works and how it can be used, and I put together two scripts I found in two different tutorials; one scrolls the page down to the marked section, and the other one scrolls it back up when a back-to-top icon is clicked (once the page has been scrolled up, the icon disappears). The problem is each of these scripts works fine on its own, but when put together with the other one something goes wrong and some parts of the scripts are not executed (depending on the order of the scripts in the code). Could anybody, please, explain to me what is wrong? As I said, I'm not working on any project, so I don't need a ready solution that would help me move on - I'm just trying to understand how all this works and what causes such conflicts. Big thanks for all your help and sorry for not being specific enough!

Here are the scripts:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    // hide #back-top first
    $("#back-top").hide();

    // fade in #back-top
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('#back-top').fadeIn(); } 
            else {
                $('#back-top').fadeOut();
            }
        });

        // scroll body to 0px on click
        $('#back-top a').click(function () {
            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 800);
            return false;
        });
    });

    });
    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var target = this.hash;
            var $target = $(target);

            $('body,html').stop().animate({
                'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
                }, 900, 'swing', function () {
                    window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: `a[href^="#"]` is also selecting the `#back-top a` so that `a` has both code apply to it. Add a class to it and use `:not(.myClassName)` to not select it

Comment: thanks! as you suggested, i used not(), and now the two scripts work just fine. the only thing I still do not get is what I should do with your comment (technically, it's not an answer, so there is no way for me to vote it up or mark as accepted, right?)